# Temporary Table not always available in Code Igniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, e-commerce, temp-tables

Code Igniter - PHP - Mysql.
I am working on a Shopping Website, and due to the large number of Products and Client Pricing Options for each Product (inclusion of Discounts at a different rate for each user etc), have created a temporary table when a Client Logs in. 
The table is creating successfully, however as I navigate thru the site it doesnt always remain persistent.

For eg, If i have a query saying "Select * From Temp_Products" running on each page of the site, it returns an empty set or says Temp_Products doesnt exist on some pages.

I am unable to figure out where the problem is, there seems to be no specific pattern or trigger causing this.

Also, how do e-commerce sites usually implement catalogues & inventry? Any info would be helpful!!

Thanks !

Comment: How long do you expect a temporary table to persist?  It is reasonable for it to persist for a mysql session, but it certainly won't last the life of a `$this->input->session`.

Comment: it doesnt last thru the loading of one page to another..not able to debug why.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in the db
es: id - id_user - id_table
after, put in the session the field that permit you to retrive the item of table.
Create a library that permit you to dialog with the data in the db es: Mytable, and in this library, create some function that get automaticaly get the items on the db, starting from the field in the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you use temporary tables there are a few pitfalls.

First of all, if you use persistent connections (which you never ever should), the temporary table will be shared among Ci-sessions since persistent connections are shared among CI-sessions. This is probably not what you want.

If you don't use persistent connections (as you should), the temporary table only lasts for the current request. Since when the CI-instance stops at the end of every request, it cleans up its database connection, which drops all temporary tables for that connection.

In your case you probably need a 'normal' table using the session-id as a key. Don't forget to clean up the sessions specific entries after the session dies. This is not easy, since codeigniter uses some delayed garbage collection mechanism for this. So you will probably need a cronjob that periodically checks whether sessions do or do not exist anymore and act upon this.